# How to redirect or respond empty response conditionally within single controller method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redirect, controller

I have following controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/foo/bar")
public classMyController 

    @PostMapping(path = "/acction")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public String doAction(@RequestBody final MyDto request) {
        try {
            someService.resetPassword(request.getSomeData());
            return "Success";
        } catch (MyException e) {
            return String.format("redirect:google.com");
        }
    }
```

The line `return "Success";` Looks redundant. Is there way to avoid it?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you want to do. Are you want to avoid multiple `return` statement?

Comment: @hamed I just don't want to respond anything in case of success

Comment: I do not get really the point, why `return "Success";` is looking redundant, it returns the success view. If it is removed, no other code takes over the action, thus no redundancy. Am I missing something or could you elaborate a little bit more on the suspected redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

Change your return type to ResponseEntity class and set response  status code inplace of String "success".

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: How to make redirect using ResponseEntity ?

Comment: Why you require redirect in this example?

Comment: It is aim of my question

Comment: Ok ideally rest api should not redirect, it should only return resource in question. If you want to redirect in exception then write your logic in @ExceptionHandler

Comment: I think my initial aproach more concise and applicable

Comment: Consider you have handled MyException and 50 places and at each place you are redirecting to Google, wouldn't it be more consise to write one exception handler across all controllers?

Comment: But Consider you have handled MyException and 50 places and at each place you are redirecting to Different URLS depends on enpoint

Comment: Ok your Choice.